# How do I tell Bazel where Python.h lives?

Tags: bazel

I'm building a C++ executable that needs to #include "Python.h" from the user's Python installation.

To express Python.h (and the various header files it includes) in Bazel, I need to know where the Python include directory is. This location will be different on Windows and Linux, and I'd like a single Bazel configuration to build them both.

What's the best Bazel practice for referencing software that exists outside of the WORKSPACE root?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So to tell Bazel about external dependencies you need to use one of the [Workspace Rules](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_local_repository.build_file_content) to specify the location of the external dependency, as well as the `BUILD` file for Bazel to use with that external dependency.

To have something work cross-platform you need to use the [select()](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select) function to have Bazel select the proper library to build against for your host operating system.

Here's a stab at accomplishing it:

First we have the `WORKSPACE` file in your project's root that defines the two libraries and the `BUILD` file to use for them. Here I'm just using `build_file_content` but if that becomes too complex you can put it in it's own file and reference it instead. The `BUILD` file here exposes the prebuild library shipped with Python along with the header files needed. It also adds an include path for any targets that depend on these libraries so you can do `#include "Python.h"`

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "python_linux",
    path = "/usr",
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
    name = "python35-lib",
    srcs = ["lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5.so"],
    hdrs = glob(["include/python3.5/*.h"]),
    includes = ["include/python3.5"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
    """
)

new_local_repository(
    name = "python_win",
    path = "C:/Python35",
    build_file_content = """
cc_library(
    name = "python35-lib",
    srcs = ["libs/python35.lib"],
    hdrs = glob(["include/*.h"]),
    includes = ["include/"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
    """
)
```

Next the `BUILD` file for your application. Here you need to define some [config_settings](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#config_setting). This allows us to define platform dependent settings for our build. We use the cpu value to determine the host OS.

In the `cc_binary` rule we use the `select()` function to choose the correct host library to link against based on the configuration.

```
config_setting(
    name = "linux_x86_64",
    values = {"cpu": "k8"},
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

config_setting(
    name = "windows",
    values = {"cpu": "x64_windows"},
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

cc_binary(
    name="python-test",
    srcs = [
        "main.c",
    ],
    deps = select({
        "//:linux_x86_64": [
            "@python_linux//:python35-lib"
        ],
        "//:windows": [
            "@python_win//:python35-lib"
        ]
    })
)
```

FWIW here's the `main.c` I was playing around with to get this working.

```
#include "Python.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print('Today is',ctime(time()))\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Another way (and perhaps simpler) is checking the python headers and libraries into your repository. You will still need to use `select()` to choose the correct library to link against but at least you won't need to add anything to your `WORKSPACE` file and can just rely on another `BUILD` file in your repository. If you look at the [Bazel repo](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel) they check in lots of external dependencies into the `third_party` directory, so it's a common practice.

Comment: This works great, tested with python 3.9!
One thing to note is that I had to modify the `cc_library` to use
  `hdrs = glob(["include/pythonX.X/**/*.h"])` as I got `fatal error: cpython/object.h: No such file or directory` when building .