# Python.h not found building from Tensorflow from source in virtualenv

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

When building tensorflow using a virtualenv I get the following error:

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

This usually means that the python-dev package needs to be installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

In my case it is installed but bazel doesn't know where to look for `Python.h` because the Python interpreter exists in the virtualenv. Is there a way of including the system's Python header file without [changing the bazel workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471120/how-do-i-tell-bazel-where-python-h-lives)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable before building with bazel (see [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/327#issuecomment-313846048)):

```
export PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/include/python3.6m"
bazel build ...
```

You can find this directory path using the following command:

```
find / -name Python.h 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This code did not resolve the issue for me: export PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH="/usr/include/python2.7"