# Finding Shared Library File: libpython3.x.so for Including Python.h in C++ when built with bazel

Tags: c++, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, bazel

I am trying to find libpython3.6.so (this is how I imported Python.h in my C++ code built with bazel as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45471120/how-do-i-tell-bazel-where-python-h-lives)).

On my other laptop, I could find it in:

```
lib/python3.x/config-3.xm-x86_64-linux-gnu
```

When I installed on my newer laptop, this folder does not exist.

I installed python on my newer laptop with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.x
```

I would appreciate suggestions where to find the file or for other ways to include Python.h when using Bazel.

Answer (score 1):

with the deadsnakes PPA the shared library file `libpython3.x.so` should be located in a different directory.

You could do a `find`

```
    sudo find / -name "libpython3.6.so" if you found nothing try this sudo `apt-get install python3.6-dev` then try the `find` again. For including `Python.h` when using `Bazel` you could use the `cc_library` like the example below.

cc_library(
    name = "python_lib",
    srcs = glob(["path/to/your/cpp/files/*.cpp"]),
    hdrs = glob(["path/to/your/cpp/files/*.h"]),
    includes = ["/usr/include/python3.6"],  # Replace with the path to your Python.h
    linkopts = ["-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", "-lpython3.6"],  # Replace with the path to your libpython3.6.so
    copts = ["-fPIC"],
)
```